# Checking for same adjacent number in a matrix

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, matrix

Hey I'm trying to build a function that checks if a N*N matrix has at least two adjacent (up-down-left right) same numbers ( numbers go from 0 to h-1) and returns 1 if does, 0 if it doesn't.
I wanted to first check along the rows if the upcoming element was the same, and than I did the same along the columns. However I have to be careful with the last elements since board[n][j] or board[i][n] don't  exist. This is what I wrote, is there a faster way to solve this problem? Also, my solution is correct?

```
int check (game_t *p){
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<p->n;i++){
      for (j=0;j<p->n-1;j++){
               if(p->board[i][j]==p->board[i][j+1]) return 1;}}
for (j=0;j<p->n;j++){
      for (i=0;i<p->n-1;i++){
               if(p->board[i][j]==p->board[i+1][j]) return 1;}}
return 0;
}
```

The structure game is defined:

```
typedef struct game {
int h;
int n;
int ** board;
} game_t;
```

Comment: Are you asking us if your homework is correct? What happens when you test it?

Comment: It seems like it works but I'm not sure if my programm covers all the possibilities and if it's the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: It returns the right answer but maybe is not the cleverest way.

Comment: What is the type of `p->board[0][0]`? I'm guessing `int`? Can you please edit your question and post the definition of `game_t`? With that information the code can probably be simplified and made faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight bit of restructuring. We can combine the row adjacency tests and the column adjacency tests into a single loop.

When checking a given row, we can compare against the previous value of the row. But, we can also check the value against the value below it in the next row.

We can do this in a single loop of the row values. So, we only need *one* set of nested `for` loops and not two.

We add a special loop at the end to check the final row [*without* a check for the next row].

Also, by adding some additional `int *` pointers to point to the rows being compared, we can simplify the `board` matrix indexing and eliminate some repetitive extra pointer/value fetches.

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
typedef struct game {
    int h;
    int n;
    int **board;
} game_t;

int
check(game_t *p)
{
    int n = p->n;
    int nm1 = n - 1;
    int yidx;
    int xidx;
    int xcur;
    int xprev;
    int *rowtop;
    int *rowbot;

    // check most rows
    yidx = 0;
    for (;  yidx < nm1;  ++yidx) {
        // point to current row of board
        rowtop = p->board[yidx];

        // point to next row of board
        rowbot = p->board[yidx + 1];

        // get the "previous" value in the current row
        xprev = rowtop[0];

        // check all values in given row
        for (xidx = 1;  xidx < n;  ++xidx, xprev = xcur) {
            // get current value
            xcur = rowtop[xidx];

            // does it match the previous value in the row?
            if (xcur == xprev)
                return 1;

            // check current value against value just below it in the next row
            if (xcur == rowbot[xidx])
                return 1;
        }
    }

    // check last row
    rowtop = p->board[yidx];
    xprev = rowtop[0];
    for (xidx = 1;  xidx < n;  ++xidx, xprev = xcur) {
        xcur = rowtop[xidx];
        if (xcur == xprev)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above will work and be *quite* fast.

But, *I'm* "insane" for speed, so, a *minor* tweak to minimize memory fetches [slightly]:

```
typedef struct game {
    int h;
    int n;
    int **board;
} game_t;

int
check(game_t *p)
{
    int n = p->n;
    int yidx;
    int xidx;
    int xcur;
    int xprev;
    const int *rowtop;
    const int *rowbot;

    // check most rows
    rowtop = p->board[0];
    for (yidx = 1;  yidx < n;  ++yidx, rowtop = rowbot) {
        // point to next row of board
        rowbot = p->board[yidx];

        // get the "previous" value in the current row
        xprev = rowtop[0];

        // check all values in given row
        for (xidx = 1;  xidx < n;  ++xidx, xprev = xcur) {
            // get current value
            xcur = rowtop[xidx];

            // does it match the previous value in the row?
            if (xcur == xprev)
                return 1;

            // check current value against value just below it in the next row
            if (xcur == rowbot[xidx])
                return 1;
        }
    }

    // check last row
    xprev = rowtop[0];
    for (xidx = 1;  xidx < n;  ++xidx, xprev = xcur) {
        xcur = rowtop[xidx];
        if (xcur == xprev)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!It works perfectly.